# Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;

            SPSiteDataQuery query = new SPSiteDataQuery();

            query.Lists = "<Lists>" +
                          "<List ID=\"" + web.Lists.TryGetList("StaffNews").ID.ToString() + "\" />"+
                          "<List ID=\"" + web.Lists.TryGetList("CompanyNews").ID.ToString() + "\" />"+
                          "<List ID=\"" + web.Lists.TryGetList("ManagementNews").ID.ToString() + "\" />" +

                          "</Lists>";

            Guid listItemId = new Guid(HiddenFieldID.Value);

            DataTable dt = web.GetSiteData(query);

                list["Nickname"] = TextBoxName.Text;
                list["_Comments"] = TextBoxComment.Text;
                list.Update();
```

Comment: I would recomand to check lists existence prior to constructing the SPSiteDataQuery as the TryGetList returns NULL if list is not found.

Comment: Also, you didn't actually executed yet the Query

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but your code is quite faulty. You do a list loop (all Lists in the current Web) and then try to update one particular SPListItem by with what ID??

```
//this retrieve a LIST Item, start with a listItemId created from what??
SPListItem itemToUpdate = list.GetItemByUniqueId(listItemId);
```

You should really review what are you trying to achieve, because the code it doesn't entirely make sense.

[EDIT] - As it seems you are trying to update all result across the 3 specified list after retrieving results using SPSiteDataQuery. In order to achieve that you need:

1. Use SPSiteDataQuery but also include the UniqueId as return field
2. Use the resulting DataTable to loop through the rows while retrieving the SPListItem based on that UniqueId (at this step SPList is no longer needed, because using the paretn SPWeb it could easily achieved)
3. Perform the update.

See here to get you started up to the point where DataTable is populated http://chakkaradeep.com/index.php/retrieving-an-item-from-the-rootweb-and-subwebs-using-its-uniqueid

Comment: i am trying to get the UniqueID from 3 lists i dont really know how to solve this because i want to get it by the unique Id for geting from one list i use Splist and splistitem but when i have 3 lists with spsitedataquery i dont really know how to get the 3 list by the uniqueId

Comment: ok, then the 1st part should be enough (remove the foreach loop) and simply add a call to execute the query too.

Comment: i dont get how to solve this.. i want to update the specified UniqueId that has two column comment and nickname the columns data i will get from the textboxes??.  I have updated in the top.

Comment: ok, i believe i begin to understand what you are trying to achieve: 1. get content from all these 3 lists and 2. update those in all records the values of 2 columns with text-box values. I'm sorry but the SPSiteDataQUery is for rollup, does not allow also updates on results. For that you still need add the UniqueId fied in the List of ViewFields, then use it to load via SPListItem (for each list Item, not each list) and then directly retrieve the SPListItem, see here http://chakkaradeep.com/index.php/retrieving-an-item-from-the-rootweb-and-subwebs-using-its-uniqueid

Comment: foreach (SPListItem list in what should i write here)

Answer (score 0):

Adding a Stacktrace to the output will help to find the error.

Just add

```
    catch (Exception x)
    {
        LabelComment.Text = x.Message + x.StackTrace;
    }
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.stacktrace(v=vs.90).aspx for more information on the StackTrace property.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, in addition to C.Marius answers you should wrap ID with **"** marks. So instead of

```
"<List ID=" + web.Lists.TryGetList("StaffNews").ID.ToString() + " />"
```

write

```
"<List ID=\"" + web.Lists.TryGetList("StaffNews").ID.ToString() + "\" />"
```